# When is the scatter matrix in linear discriminant analysis singular?

Tags: discriminant-analysis, linear-algebra

In linear discriminant analysis (LDA), when there are fewer data instances than the number of dimensions (i.e., when the data matrix is of order $n \times m$ where $n$ is less than $m$), the within-class scatter matrix $S_W$ is said to be singular. Does this mean that a scatter matrix generated from any $n\times m$ data matrix where $n$ is less than $m$ is guaranteed to give a singular $S_W$ matrix? How much smaller does $n$ have to be in comparison to $m$ for $S_W$ matrix to be guaranteed singular?

Comment: Yes, it means exactly that.